# Getting Google Play billing and digital goods API working with a PWA (progressive web app)

Tags: google-api, google-play, progressive-web-apps

Having developed a PWA in Blazor WASM, I have successfully deployed an internal test version through Google Play. The next step I need is to add subscriptions through Google Play. To implement this, Google suggests here that I need to register for "an origin trial" for the Digital Goods API.

[https://chromeos.dev/en/publish/pwa-play-billing](https://developer.chrome.com/origintrials/#/view_trial/888335026498830337)

> *Note: The Digital Goods API is currently available through an Origin Trial⁠ - a mechanism that allows developers early access to new Web APIs. You will need to register for the Digital Goods API v2 origin trial⁠ and request a token, which you will need to provide on any pages in your origin⁠.*

However, the link they provide to do this goes here:
https://developer.chrome.com/origintrials/#/view_trial/888335026498830337

> *Available
> Chrome 96 to 100
> End date
> 23 May 2022*

That end date is over one year ago. So does this mean you don't need to do that, or that the trial is over, or that I can implement this, but it might have support pulled at any point? I don't want to invest time on this if Google might pull the rug out any day. Is this just a case of Google having very out of date documentation?

Is anyone successfully using the digital goods API with a PWA and not jumping through this hoop of registering for something that seems already to have expired?

I have already tried to register for this, there is no link, only notification that this trial has ended over a year ago.